# Short circuit and giving incorrect results?

Tags: perl, short-circuiting, operation

I am experiencing strange results with Perl's short circuited and, that is `&&`.

I am trying to solve a Project Euler problem where I want a certain number to be divisible by a list of numbers.

```
$b=42;

if($b%21==0 && b%2==0 && b%5==2){print "Why not?"};
```

Should print `"Why not"` as far as I can see, but keeps silent.

```
$b=42;

if($b%21==0 && b%2==0 && b%5==0){print "WTF?"};
```

Should keep silent, but prints `"WTF?"`.

What gives?

Comment: Thats a reason to always write with `use strict;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Rohit answered, the solution is to add the `$` before the `b`. The exact reason it doesn't print `"Why not?"` but prints `"WTF`" is this: when you give the `b` without the `$` sign (and without `use strict;` in force), Perl treats the `b` as the string `"b"`. Then when you apply the operator `%` on it, since `%` is a numerical operator, Perl looks within the string `"b"` and checks whether it starts with a number. Since it doesn't, Perl takes the numerical value of `"b"` as 0, and then applies the mod (%) operation. 0%5 is 0 and not 2, so `WTF` is printed and not `"Why not?"`

Answer (score 8):

Always use `use strict` and `use warnings`.

You are using your last two `b's` as bareword, which will be shown as warning - `"Unquoted string "b" may clash with future reserved word"`

You need to change your `if` to: -

```
if($b%21==0 && $b%2==0 && $b%5==2){print "Why not?"};
```

and: -

```
if($b%21==0 && $b%2==0 && $b%5==0){print "WTF?"};
```

gives expected results.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat It does, if you `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Answer (score 2):

if($b%21==0 && $b%2==0 && $b%5==2){print "Why not?"};

works over here, you forgot the $, but apearntly you already found it :)